# R: hts package, label crop in plot

Tags: r, time-series, r-hts

I am using the [hts package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/index.html), which in it's newest version 4.x has a better label naming handling. Unfortunately stll labels get cropped in plots of an hts object.

```
bts <- ts(5 + matrix(sort(rnorm(500)), ncol=5, nrow=100))
y <- hts(bts, nodes=list(2, c(3, 2)))
plot(y, levels = c(0, 1))
```

This is especialy a problem when handling lengthy label names. Any idea how to avoid this cropping?

[image: Plot hts]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use `plot(y, levels = c(0, 1), labels = FALSE)` and add labels yourself using the `text()` function.

Alternatively, `plot(y, include = 70)` gives 70 historical observations to get rid of the overlapping labels, if showing the whole time series is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel both solutions quite hacky, which should not be necessary. I was looking for something which needs less manual control. Maybe the hts package is too limited right now. Hope Rob can consider for future versions. I raised an issue on Github https://github.com/robjhyndman/hts/issues/2 .

Comment: I tried to fix that, but the base `plot()` function is so limited. Because this also depends on the size of user's plotting window.